# How can I add an aggregate percentage to an SSRS report based on two specific columns in a matrix?

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, calculated-columns

I am somewhat new to SSRS and I have built a matrix report that looks fairly simple:

```
Supplier           [AccDate]
[SupplierName]     Sum(PurchasingCredit)
Total              <<Expr>>
```

The actual report shows month-by-month sales data for a year in addition to Current YTD and Previous YTD columns (joined via UNION clause in base query) in addition to a column showing Year-over-Year % as difference between the Current YTD and Previous YTD columns (also joined via union).

I was able to apply a dynamic format to the Year-over-Year column using the following expression in the Format property to show the YOY column as a percentage and the others as dollar amounts:

```
=IIF(Fields!AccDate.Value <> "YOY", "'$' #,0.00;'$' -#,0.00", "#,0.00 %;-#,0.00 %")
```

The last thing I need to do is to show the column totals, which are working for each column with the exception of the year-over-year percentages using the following:

```
=IIF(Fields!AccDate.Value <> "YOY", SUM(Fields!PurchasingCredit.Value), 0)
```

In the year-over-year (YOY) column, a sum of percentages doesn't make sense: I need it to recalculate this value based on the sums of the "CYTD" and "PYTD" columns, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am guessing it is probably an application of scope, but the MS articles that attempt to explain this are very confusing.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the expected results for this data?

Comment: The original query returns five columns: SupplierName, SupplierId, PurchasingCredit, AccDate, and ColOrder (used to order the columns on display).  The columns displayed by the report are: Mon1, Mon2, Mon3, Mon4, Mon5, Mon6, Mon7, Mon8, Mon9, Mon10, Mon11, Mon12, Mon13, CYTD, PYTD, and YOY and are all generated sets from SQL.  A Typical return result set is 12K rows condensing to final display of 16 columns by 150 rows + total.  I'd post a screenshot but I am new to this forum.  Can't post any more than that.

Comment: Just a note, but the column sets consist of one query that gets all data for columns Mon(X), one union query to add in CYTD, one union query to add in PYTD, and union query to add in YOY.  The actual query is quite complex, so I can't post it here.

Comment: So instead of banging my head against the wall, I just added two more datasets to get me the sums and modified the expression thus:  [=IIF(Fields!AccDate.Value <> "YOY"
    , SUM(Fields!PurchasingCredit.Value)
    , Sum(Fields!CYTD_PC_Total.Value, "CYTD_Total")/Sum(Fields!PYTD_PC_Total.Value, "PYTD_Total")-1
)]  It takes a few more seconds to render, but it works.  Would still be interested in a report/column-based solution.